# Azure database Security: Where should I store the db password?

Tags: spring, database, azure, spring-boot, backend

It is my first experience with deploying an app (spring boot) to Azure.
My app needs a PostgreSQL server.
So, I installed a minimal PostgreSQL server on Azure attached to my Resource group.

Obviously, I need to know the password of the database in order to connect it.
So, I put it in the BE properties file.

```
spring.datasource.password=MySbPassword     (just an example of course)
```

I guess this is not the best method in terms of information security.

What is the best practice to store the database password from security point of view, also given the code is stored on a public Github repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Environment Variables in your code. The value for the environment variables will be set during your Release process. If you're using Azure Devops, the right place to store the password is in Azure Key Vault. (and retrieved in your pipeline using Azure Key Vault Task)